# Subtract values in one column by using filter of other two

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to subtract values of one column. The data is big so I need to filer it. Query works but it does not display correct results.

First I choose filter where I type height and warehouse(checkboxes are used to allow multiple selection for warehouse).

```
$debljina=[$_POST'debljina'];

Then I made query for warehouse 

    if (!empty($skladiste)) {

        $sklad="SELECT `ReprMatId` FROM `jos_ib_repromaterijali` WHERE `ReprMatSkladiste` = '$skladiste[0]'";
            if(sizeof($skladiste)>0){
                for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($skladiste); $i++) { 
                    $sklad.="OR ReprMatSkladiste = '$skladiste[$i]'";
                }

            }
        }

echo "<table border='2' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";  
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
echo "<td width='100' align='center'>Ukupna količina repromaterijala na skladištu DEBLJINA: $debljina (kg)</td>";  

$total = " SELECT SUM(ReprMatTrenutnaKolicina) FROM `jos_ib_repromaterijali` WHERE `ReprMatDebljina`= '$debljina' AND
jos_ib_repromaterijali.ReprMatId IN(".$sklad.") ";  
/echo $total;

$totalquantity=mysqli_query($con, $total);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($totalquantity))  
{  
echo "<tr'>";  
echo "<td align='center' width='400' height='30'>" . $row['SUM(ReprMatTrenutnaKolicina)'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>";  
}  
echo "</table>";
```

when I echo total quantity I get query:

```
SELECT SUM(ReprMatTrenutnaKolicina) FROM `jos_ib_repromaterijali` WHERE `ReprMatDebljina`= '0.5' AND jos_ib_repromaterijali.ReprMatId IN(SELECT `ReprMatId` FROM `jos_ib_repromaterijali` WHERE ReprMatSkladiste = '1' OR ReprMatSkladiste = '6')
```

I get result but something is wrong and I can not figure it out.. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `$row['SUM(ReprMatTrenutnaKolicina)']`

Change your select statement in your query to:

```
SELECT SUM(ReprMatTrenutnaKolicina) as NUM [...]
```

And then do the following to access the value:

```
$row['NUM']
```